# Compressing and formatting photos added into Word document with Python

Tags: python, image, ms-word

I want to automate adding photos into a word document using Python but sometimes run into issues with having too many photos and thus running into issues with Word freezing. Is there a way to compress the photos with the Document library? I also would like to have 6 photos to a page, but the end result with my current code places them as a single column.

This is my code so far:

```
import os
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

file_list=[]
for (dirname, dirs, files) in os.walk('.'):
   for filename in files:
       if filename.endswith('.jpeg'):
           file_list.append(filename)


document = Document()

for i in range(len(file_list)):
    document.add_picture(file_list[i],width=Inches(3.2))
```

Comment: As it stands, your question is too broad: 2 distinct questions. You might want to use the [edit] link to remove one question. Then you can ask the second in a separate Question.

Comment: Which version of Word is involved? The graphics tools available differ quite a bit from version to version. It would probably be better, though, for you to compress the graphics files using a dedicated graphics tool *before* inserting them into Word. Word is most emphatically *not* a graphics editor and its capabilities in this respect are very limited.

Comment: In which line that I have listed would the version of Word affect the Document library commands? Do you have a reccomendation for a graphics library?